# Why "either' is not a Demonstrative pronoun while "neither" can be one?

Tags: pronouns, demonstrative

Why "either' is not a Demonstrative pronoun while "neither" can be one?

I found it from this source that "neither" can be a demonstrative pronoun.
So I am curious why "either" can't be?

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Demonstrative-Pronouns.htm

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that grammar book is very useful. If _Neither_ is a demonstrative pronoun, so is _either_. And it is simply not true that _neither_ cannot take a plural verb: The iWeb corpus has 2072 instances of "Neigher of [word] [plural verb]" and 6623 of "Neither of [word] [singular verb]"

Comment: Neither boy was well. Either boy could have been.